# Eclipse, format if statements to one line statement

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to create an automatic formatter that changes :

```
if (foo.length > 1)
   bar = foo[1];
else
    bar = "";
```

to

```
bar = (foo.length > 1) ? foo[1] : "";
```

How can I make `shift+ctrl+f` auto organize this ?

Comment: That is not *formatting*; that is refactoring. But I am not aware that eclipse has support for such operations. And it wouldn't surprise me if IntelliJ on the other hand ... would offer something like this.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that IntelliJ gained a lot of "java IDE" market over the last ... 12 to 24 months. Simply because they keep adding interesting new technology to the core element - the java editor - with every release. Whereas "eclipse" is working on a lot of things; but somehow not adding features to that "core" part of their product. It means: IntelliJ has more features. If that is what "better" means to you, then yes, IntelliJ is "better".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin is specifically for changing if-else blocks into ternary operators.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spartan-refactoring-0

Comment: Thx :) That's exactly what I need